# Deprecated( message = "moved to val", replaceWith = ReplaceWith(expression = "code"), level = DeprecationLevel.ERROR)

Tags: okhttp

why okhttp4.x use the replaceWith to forbid developer to get response's code like response.code(). Deprecated( message = "moved to val", replaceWith = ReplaceWith(expression = "code"), level = DeprecationLevel.ERROR)

why okhttp4.x use the replaceWith to forbid developer to get response's code like response.code(). Deprecated( message = "moved to val", replaceWith = ReplaceWith(expression = "code"), level = DeprecationLevel.ERROR)

Answer (score 0):

In OkHttp 4.x, the `Response.code()` method has been deprecated in favor of using the `code` property. This change improves the readability and consistency of the code. To get the response code, use `response.code` instead of `response.code()`.